# How to Detect Email that Lands in Inbox vs Spam of User with Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-ses

I would like to detect emails that arrive in the inbox (vs emails that land in the spam folder) sent using Amazon SES.

I know that I can set up notifications for delivered emails, bounced email, and emails with complaints.

When you get a delivery notification, does it mean that the email landed in the inbox and not in the spam folder, or does it only mean that the email didn't bounce and that the email provider didn't reject the email?

And if it only means that the email didn't bounce, is there a way to know what emails actually land in the inbox vs automatically landing in the spam folder of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know this information:

This is not specific to SES, but all email in general.

Each email reading application will handle SPAM in different way.

For example, in GMAIL, items in SPAM folder will not render or download external resources.

You will not be able to detect if a message has never been viewed and in an Inbox -vs- Spam folder.